# Python.h fails importing package

Tags: python, c++

I am using `Python.h` in C++ to run some Python code. Since I have no access to the `main` function, I am doing everything in my own function which gets called at some point. I am experiencing a weird failure when importing a package which unfortunately cannot reproduce in an external MWE. My code goes something like this:

```cpp
void my_function(void) {
    Stuff not related to Python here...
    
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* signals_module = PyImport_ImportModule("signals");
    PyErr_Print();
    std::cout << (signals_module == nullptr) << std::endl; // This prints `1`
    PyObject* PeakSignal_class = PyObject_GetAttrString(signals_module, "PeakSignal"); // Of course segmentation fault

    
    More stuff...
}
```

The line where it imports the `signal` package fails, and `PyErr_Print` prints this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_RecursionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/code/signals/signals/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from signals.PeakSignal import PeakSignal
  File "/home/me/code/signals/signals/PeakSignal.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Signal import Signal
  File "/home/me/code/signals/signals/Signal.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_RecursionError
```

Now, the following MWE works flawlessly:

```cpp
// Compile with `g++ -o deleteme -I/usr/include/python3.10 deleteme_2.cpp -lpython3.10`

#include <Python.h>

void f() {
    Py_Initialize();
    
    // Import the signals module
    PyObject* signalsModule = PyImport_ImportModule("signals");

    // Get a reference to the PeakSignal class
    PyObject* peakSignalClass = PyObject_GetAttrString(signalsModule, "PeakSignal");

    // Create an instance of the PeakSignal class with the arguments [1,2,3] and [2,3,4]
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, PyList_New(3));
    PyList_SetItem(PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0), 0, PyLong_FromLong(1));
    PyList_SetItem(PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0), 1, PyLong_FromLong(2));
    PyList_SetItem(PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0), 2, PyLong_FromLong(3));
    PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, PyList_New(3));
    PyList_SetItem(PyTuple_GetItem(args, 1), 0, PyLong_FromLong(2));
    PyList_SetItem(PyTuple_GetItem(args, 1), 1, PyLong_FromLong(3));
    PyList_SetItem(PyTuple_GetItem(args, 1), 2, PyLong_FromLong(4));
    PyObject* peakSignalInstance = PyObject_CallObject(peakSignalClass, args);

    // Get the time and samples attributes from the PeakSignal instance
    PyObject* time = PyObject_GetAttrString(peakSignalInstance, "time");
    PyObject* samples = PyObject_GetAttrString(peakSignalInstance, "samples");

    // Print the results
    PyObject* strTime = PyObject_Str(time);
    PyObject* strSamples = PyObject_Str(samples);
    printf("PeakSignal:\n%s\n%s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(strTime), PyUnicode_AsUTF8(strSamples));
    Py_Finalize();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("deleteme_2.cpp\n");
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Honestly I don't know how `my_function` is called (main process, thread, etc), should that may have an impact on this. All I know is that it is called and it is failing, but cannot understand why.

Comment: One notable difference is that your MCVE calls `Py_Finalize();` but your first snippet doesn't mention this.

Comment: Btw. on our side, we noticed issues with calling `Py_Initialize()` / `Py_Finalize()` multiple times. It caused a significant amount of leaked memory for each repeated call. Hence, we call `Py_Initialize()` once at application start up only (and `Py_Finalize()` at application shutdown).

Comment: Well, it seems to me that it is really important how `my_function` is called and what is of it expected. You have not shown any code which explains that. Is it supposed to be a numpy extension?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I am not sure whether `Py_Initialize` is called before I call it. However, if I remove my call to it, then it fails in the same way as if I remove it from my MWE. So I guess it is not being called by anyone but me. With respect to the `Py_Finalize` my code never makes it more than the `PyObject_GetAttrString` and it dies, so it should not matter.

Comment: @zvone yes, my appologies. I actually don't know how is it called. I just know it is called. This is not a numpy extension, I just have to process some waveforms in C++ and want to reuse a piece of code I already have in Python. It uses numpy.

Comment: I also considered that `PyInitialize()` might be called by something else than your code before. However, my first comment wasn't coined to that opportunity but based on the assumption that your function `my_function(void)` dies unexpectedly while it's called the 2nd time. From your last reply, I assume it already dies unexpectedly on its first call. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas...